# google translator highlight

Tags: google-translate

url: http://translate.google.com/

**eg**. source lang is english, translate lang is other. and enter the text 'i' in the above page's textarea. hover the translate word, and the word background will highlight, and the 'i' will highlight.

*I want to know that blew the code how does the '.gt-hl-layer' cooperate with the '#source' work?*

```
<div style="width: 100%;"><!--from google translator-->
<div class="gt-hl-layer" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 641px; height: 65px; left: 0px; top: 0px; " dir="ltr"></div>
<textarea id="source" name="text" wrap="SOFT" tabindex="0" dir="ltr" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: auto; box-sizing: border-box; " class="goog-textarea"></textarea>
</div>
```

It's better to give some simple demo or code.
thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine it could work like this:

1. Run source through the "translation machine", it produces the translated text, and in the process does a lot of tagging (annotations) on the source -- the translation also comes with annotations.
2. The translation process determines which tokens in the source are linked to each other (e.g. phrasal verbs) and how the tokens are linked to the corresponding elements in the translation.
3. The translation text is an end product, it's generated from a dataset which had much richer annotations and tags -- using this richer set, you can have this annotated structure compiled into any other format (say, XML), or in the case of HTML, it probably takes the form of lots of spans, each with an ID.
4. On the surface, the HTML is re-fabricated for the source text too (now with the structure from the underlying annotations). It's like a tokenized text with lots of spans, each with an generated ID. Usually there's another layer that matches the text areas and carries the highlighting.
5. Then probably there's a middle part that map out which mouseover in the translation should light up which span(s) in the source.